# How to make server image for load balancing?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, server-side

I have an amazon server with I'm told 2-5 instances to handle traffic. I was told that whenever I upload the latest code to the main server I have to make an "image" of it so that the other servers can copy that image when there is more traffic and they are activated. How do I make the image? On command line? Or not. I'm uploading code through SSH. I don't know much about this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for a novice to do this is in the AWS Management Console. You can right click on your instance and select "Create an Image (EBS AMI)". Note that your image must be backed by EBS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that sounds good but now I'm being told I have to use SSH for some reason :(

Comment: http://robrohan.com/2009/01/30/saving-a-customised-linux-amazon-instance-ec2-and-s3/

If you go to this link, and start reading at "Download the Amazon AMI tools"

It gives you a pretty detailed description of how to do this from the command line. Note this is an old article, that I used in the past, when it was only instance stores, and I was learning AWS, but it should work for you now. The AWS Management Console is a far faster, and superior option if you're using EBS backed instances.

Comment: The powers the be. I think someone already installed those tools. I think the command I need is ec2-bundle-vol but I don't know if there is a step 2